# Определять значение поля модели спомощью pre_save в моделях или в представлениях при валидации?

Tags: python, django

Привет, подскажите пожалуйста, где лучше определить логику для такого случая:
У меня есть несколько моделей, одна из которых что-то типо

```
class Drawing(models.Model):
    ...
    related_file = models.FileField(upload_to=dfile_location)
    extension = models.ForeignKey("FileExtension", blank=True, null=True,
                                  related_name="+")
    ...

    @property
    def get_extension(self):
        ext = "".join(self.related_file.name.split(".")[1:])
        return ext
```

Вторая модель FileExtension которая просто содержит расширения файлов (CharField с названием extension) и первичный ключ. Хочу сделать, чтобы расширение файла определялось автоматически, поэтому в моделях сделал

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

...

def pre_save_drawing_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.extension:
        instance.extension =  FileExtension.objects.get(extension__icontains=instance.get_extension)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_drawing_receiver, sender=Drawing)
```

Вроде все работает, но я с джангой только знакомлюсь и поэтому тестировал это через админку. После, когда дело дошло до форм, в документации вычитал, что недостающие поля формы можно назначить в представлении на этапе валидации или до нее. Вот и вопрос в том, а где лучше или правильнее это делать? В моделях или в представлениях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле большого значения не имеет, но..

В данном случае Вы всё сделали правильно. Потому что, во-первых, форм у вас может быть несколько - и что, для каждой вы будете код копировать, чтобы расширение файла получать? Ну или, что конечно лучше, наследоваться. Но опять же - а вдруг у Вас первая форма ModelForm, а вторая просто Form? Для последней это вряд ли сработает в варианте "из коробки". Тут можно попробовать какие-нибудь mixin'ы задействовать, но это опять много рутиной работы.

Во-вторых, вы потом может решите всё на асинхронщину переделать и прикрутить какой-нибудь rest-framework, например. И что, в сериализаторах (аналог форм) опять определять логику для получения расширения?

Так что нет, всё у вас правильно и менять не стоит. Универсальное и надёжное решение.

p.s. А тестировать лучше не через админку, а через [тесты](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/)

Answer (score 0):

Правильным способом является вынести необходимую логику по инициализации полей перед сохранением в метод `Drawing.save()`.

```
class Drawing(models.Model):
    ...
    related_file = models.FileField(upload_to=dfile_location)
    extension = models.ForeignKey("FileExtension", blank=True, null=True, related_name="+")
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.extension:
            try:
                self.extension =  FileExtension.objects.filter(extension__icontains=self.get_extension())[0]
            except IndexError:
                # no such FileExtension
                pass
        return super(Drawing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_extension(self):
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(self.related_file.name)
        return ext.lstrip(".")
```